# Google Apis TagManager v2 example

Tags: c#, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-api-dotnet-client

I have try to call API for google TAG manager, I'm using this packege Google.Apis.TagManager.v2.

I cannot find any example, i try to use it in this way:

```
var service = new Google.Apis.TagManager.v2.TagManagerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            
            ApiKey = "my API-KEY",
        });

        //parent string GTM Workspace's API relative path. 
        //Example: accounts/{account_id}/containers/{container_id}/workspaces/{workspace_id}

        var test = service.Accounts.Containers.List("accounts/xxx/containers/yyy/workspaces/zzz");

        var result = test.Execute();
```

I receive this error:

```
Parameter validation failed for "parent"
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I would be very suprised if you could get anything out of GTM with an api key

Comment: Only example found for v1 uses ApiKey... I'm tried to convert for V2, but I failed.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

Comment: I can give you an auth example for V2 see if that helps

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag manager to my knowledge contains only private user data to access private user data you are going to need to authenticate using Oauth2.

```
     /// <summary>
        /// ** Installed Aplication only ** 
        /// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
        /// <param name="scopes">Array of Google scopes</param>
        /// <returns>TagmanagerService used to make requests against the Tagmanager API</returns>
        public static TagmanagerService GetTagmanagerService(string clientSecretJson, string userName, string[] scopes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecretJson))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecretJson");
                if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                    throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

                var cred = GetUserCredential(clientSecretJson, userName, scopes);
                return GetService(cred);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Get Tagmanager service failed.", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ** Installed Aplication only ** 
        /// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
        /// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
        /// <param name="scopes">Array of Google scopes</param>
        /// <returns>authencated UserCredential</returns>
        private static UserCredential GetUserCredential(string clientSecretJson, string userName, string[] scopes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecretJson))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecretJson");
                if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                    throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

                // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them               
                using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

                    // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                    var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                             scopes,
                                                                             userName,
                                                                             CancellationToken.None,
                                                                             new 
   FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                    credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
                    return credential;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Get user credentials failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```